# jQuery navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation bar without `a` tags:

```
    $('div.nav ul li').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).is(':first-child')) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: "0"
            }, 'slow');
        } else if($(this).is(':nth-child(2)')) {
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: "0"
            }, 'slow');
        } else if($(this).is(':nth-child(3)')) {
            var offset = $('div.features').offset().top;
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: offset+ 'px'
            }, 'slow');
        } else if($(this).is(':nth-child(4)')) {
            var offset = $(document).height();
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: offset+ 'px'
            }, 'slow');
        }
    });
```

I wondered if this way is the best way of doing this.  `first-child & nth-child(2)` goes to the same place, then each child after that - up to `4` has a different position to go to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

you could for starters derive the child position once with

```
var index =  $('div.nav ul li').index( this )
```

Then you could adapt to index `0` and `1` in 1 `if` statement
Finally, you could just derive the `index` and have the `animate` statement only once.

Something like this in the end might do:

```
$('div.nav ul li').on('click', function() {

    var index = $('div.nav ul li').index( this ), top;

    if( index < 2 ){
      top = '0';
    }
    if( index == 2 ){
      top = $('div.features').offset().top + 'px';  
    }
    if( index == 3 ){
      top = $(document).height() + 'px';  
    }
   if(top){
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: "0"
        }, 'slow');
   }
});
```